# Check status of user

Tags: node.js, discord.js

How do i check the status of a user in my server? as `user.presence.status` is depreciated. And I won't use

```
    let guild = await client.guilds.cache.find(guild => guild.id === "xxx");
    let guildMembers = await guild.members.fetch({ withPresences: true });
    var onlineMembers = await guildMembers.filter(member => !member.user.bot && member.presence?.status != "offline");
```

Since this just checks who's online but doesn't actually return the status of the specific user I need

Comment: Do you have the ID of the member?

Comment: Yes, I do have the ID of the member

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it through [<GuildMember>.presence.status](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=status), provided that the appropriate intents are enabled.

For help on intents you may want to look at the [guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents).

If you have the ID, you can do:

```js
const member = await guild.members.fetch(ID);
console.log(member.presence.status)
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when running `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'status')`

Comment: Never mind, I got it. Because I had a missing Intent. Thanks